# How do you stretch image in listview in xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i'm creating a category where it displays the different kind of dishes but i'm kinda confused on how to use xaml i tried my best to replicate my design here's the picture [image] link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dET3.jpg

and this is what i have now.
[image: present xaml] link:https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8VSu.jpg

**MenuCategories.xaml**

```
  <ListView x:Name="MyCategory" ItemSelected="MyCategory_ItemSelected" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell >


                    <Grid x:Name="Categ" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="Fill" >
                            <Image Source="{Binding cat_image ,StringFormat='https://i.imgur.com/{0:F0}.png'}" Scale="1" />
                        </StackLayout>


                        <StackLayout  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Orientation="Vertical" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Font="30" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" x:Name="categoryname" Text="{Binding cat_code}" 
                   Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" />
                        </StackLayout>

                    </Grid>


                </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

  </ListView>
```

my problem is on how you expand the the width of list in Listview just like in the first image, please help thank you in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have other views you plan on adding into those Row/Columns your `ListView` contains several unnecessary views in your layout. All you should have to do is set `RowHeight` on your `ListView` and have a `Grid` with an `Image` with `Aspect="AspectFill"`. Keep in mind depending on the images aspect ratio it may crop some of the images to get it to fill the entire grid.

```
<ListView RowHeight="200">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                    <Label VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Sorry, might be off topic but how did you format XAML code in the post?

Comment: Look here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-I-format-my-code-blocks and if you're posting from the app it's not quite so friendly